# Strange variable behavior in Draggabilly jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Ok guys, i have no idea what's going on here. Im using this plugin (http://draggabilly.desandro.com/) and making a drag & drop grid (or something similar). Here's the pen (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbKjzx) and here the code:

// external js: draggabilly.pkgd.js

```
$(document).ready( function() {


    for(var i=1;i<=12;i++) {
        $(".inventory").append('<div class="item"></div>');
    }

    for (var i = 0; $('.item').length + 1 > i; i++){
        var n = i.toString();
        var $item = $('.item:nth-child(' + i + ')');
        $item.text(n);
        var offsetX = $item.css("left");
        var offsetY = $item.css("top");

        $item.addClass(n);
        $item.draggabilly();
        $item.css("background-color","green");


        $("." + n).on("dragStart",function(){
            $(this).css({"transition": "none", "z-index": "9999", "background-color": "red"})
            .mousemove(function(e){
                $(this).on("dragEnd",function(){
                    $(this).css("top",offsetY);
                    $(this).css("left",offsetX);

                    var posX = e.pageX;
                    var posY = e.pageY;
                    var thisItsTheVariable = $("p").height();

                    $(this).css({"transition": "all .3s", "z-index": "1"});
                })              
            })
        })
    }    
})
```

The weird thing comes with thisItsTheVariable. When you assign to the variable any other value, there is an animation when you drop the dive and this come back to its original place. Even with $("p").css("background-color") or something similar works. But when you use .css("top"), .css("left"), .css("height"), .css("width"), .height(), .width() and possibly other (i didn't try it all), the animation dissapears! What is happening here?

Comment: Why that `for` loop instead of `$(".item").each()`?

Comment: You're not doing anything with the variable `thisItsVariable`. Just assigning the variable causes this problem?

Comment: I suspect the problem is that anything that deals with positions and sizes of elements needs to force rendering, which interferes with animation.

Comment: @Barmar, I read in some article that for loop is much faster than each() (it was very well explained and it had graphics about the rendiment of both). I know in the code i'm doing nothing with the variable, and thats why i dont understand what's happening. I want to use it later, but first i have to fix this problem. I understand what you mean, but is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Yes, it's intrinsically faster, but then you slow it down by calling `$('.item:nth-child('+n+')')` in the loop to access each element. That's almost certainly more than the overhead of `.each`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `$("p").height()` after you start the animation seems to fix it.

```js
// external js: draggabilly.pkgd.js

$(document).ready(function () {


    for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
        $(".inventory").append('<div class="item"></div>');
    }

    for (var i = 0; $('.item').length + 1 > i; i++) {
        var n = i.toString();
        var $item = $('.item:nth-child(' + i + ')');
        $item.text(n);
        var offsetX = $item.css("left");
        var offsetY = $item.css("top");

        $item.addClass(n);
        $item.draggabilly();
        $item.css("background-color", "green");


        $("." + n).on("dragStart", function () {
            $(this).css({
                "transition": "none",
                "z-index": "9999",
                "background-color": "red"
            })
                .mousemove(function (e) {
                $(this).on("dragEnd", function () {
                    $(this).css("top", offsetY);
                    $(this).css("left", offsetX);

                    var posX = e.pageX;
                    var posY = e.pageY;
                     

                    $(this).css({"transition": "all .3s", "z-index": "1"});
                    var thisItsTheVariable = $("p").height();
                })
            })
        })
    }
})
```

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
.inventory {
    height: 300px;
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px black solid;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.item {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #F90;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px black solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/draggabilly/1.2.0/draggabilly.pkgd.js"></script>
<div class="inventory"></div>
<p></p>
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what i want. Thanks!